# Lookup ticket data for various groups located on one sheet and move to another sheet based on group name

Tags: excel, indexing, reference, match, lookup

I have a sheet with service ticket data on it, things like ticket number, opened time, assignment group, etc. I then have tabs with the various group names that I currently have to manually sort and copy past over to each tab. I am trying to use INDEX MATCH to dynamically reference the data based on the group name, but the formula is only returning the first item that matches the group name referenced. See code below. I feel like there is a way to do this without using VBA, but if someone things VBA is the way to go then that is fine. Thanks for the assistance.

`=INDEX('Format Page'!$A:$M,MATCH("Group A",'Format Page'!$H:$H,0),MATCH('Group A'!A$1,'Format Page'!$A$1:$M$1,0))`

Where `'Group A'!A$1` is the name of the group tab and A1 is the column for ticket number. When I drag this formula down I just get the first ticket that matches the group name. 
[image: Example Sheet]

[image: Example Sheet]

Comment: Could you add some example data and desired output?

Comment: Each sheet with the group name, I.E. Group A, has the same columns as the Format Page, in the same order. Number, Opened Time, Assignment group, etc. I am just trying to match each column from the specific group name sheet with the matching group name on the Format Page sheet. So on each group name sheet ideally when I pasted in the new ticket data from the current day each specific group name sheet would automatically populate with their specific group, instead of me having to filter by group name on the format page and copy the data over to each individual group sheet.

Comment: And column "Assignment group" would contain your group name, like "Group A", "Group B", and so on?

Comment: Correct. I have added 2 example pictures of what the sheet looks like.

Comment: You are not going to want Formula for this, unless you have the new dynamic array formula: `FILTER()` as [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328260/4851590) below.  Other wise they will by array type formulas and pages full of these formula will slow down the calc.  You will want to use vba to copy the correct lines to the correct sheets or use an advanced filter.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to office 365 for the new Filter function. Do you have any thoughts on where to start with the VBA method? It's been a while since I have done any VBA programming and the solution is on the tip of my brain, but I can't remember all of the correct syntax. I am thinking if I count the number of cells where the group name is equal to the group I want for each page and then iterate through that number for each column that will get me what I want, but I can't get all the way there.

Answer (score 1):

As simple solution would be using the new dynamic arrays. The `FILTER` function is probably giving you the right result (type it into `A2` on the `Group A` tab)

```
=FILTER('Format page'!A2:H9,'Format page'!H2:H9="Group A")
```

The nice thing about it is that the array will automatically grow when your source data (the `Format page`) grows.

However, this will only work if dynamic arrays are already available to you (if you use an updated Office 365, you might be lucky).

Your **source data** looks like this:

[image: Source data for FILTER function in Excel]

The `FILTER` function will give you this **output**:

[image: Result of the FILTER function in Excel]

Observe that you do not need to "drag" down this dynamic array. It will grow automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Office 2016, so I seem to only have the FILTERXML formula available.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on where to start with the VBA method? It's been a while since I have done any VBA programming and the solution is on the tip of my brain, but I can't remember all of the correct syntax. I am thinking if I count the number of cells where the group name is equal to the group I want for each page and then iterate through that number for each column that will get me what I want, but I can't get all the way there.